# Wrap few maven plugins into single one

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, gradle-plugin, gradle-task

Is it possible to wrap few maven plugins into single one? Like I want to wrap checkstyle plugin, spotbugs & pmd plugins into single one named static-code-analyse plugin and execute all of them at once.

In the Gradle there is some kind on task wrapper which can be used for such cases. I wonder does it possible to do something like that with maven?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't put multiple plugins in a plugin. What you can do is have multiple plugins in the `<plugins>` tag. However, if you want to wrap multiple plugins and then execute them you should use *Maven Build Profiles*

These profiles are then for example triggered by a *Jenkins Pipeline*

For more details on maven profiles visit this link:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html